# Drop Down List Event for Selection Change

Tags: drop-down-menu

I have two Drop Down Lists. One Drop Down List is for Countries and Other is for States. Country Drop Down List has following values:
India
USA
England
Canada
If I select India From this list, The states of India should appear in the states drop down list. Please tell me which event of Country Drop Down List should I choose?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your previous questions, it looks like you are asking specifically for c#. If this is the case and if you are referring to the WinForms ComboBox, then try out the comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged event.